Why Navigator push seems to be not working in small snippet
This seems like it should work, doesn't work in dartpad either.
Usually I use combination of named routes and the static navigator push and pop and I can get the behavior I want for multiple pushes, so I am confused how this doesn't work.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
      // onGenerateRoute: TestRouter.generateRoute,
      home:A()));
}


class A extends StatefulWidget {
  const A({ super.key });
  State createState() => AState();
}
class AState extends State {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("A"),
        ),
        body:
    ListView(children: [
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
            return B();
          },
          ));
        },
      child:Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        height: 100, width: 100, child: Center(child:Text("B")),)),
    ],)
    );
  }
}


class B extends StatefulWidget {
  const B({ super.key });
  State createState() => BState();
}
class BState extends State {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("B"),
        ),
        body:
    ListView(children: [
      GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
              return C();
            }));
          },
          child:Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            height: 100, width: 100, child: Center(child:Text("C")),)),
    ],)
    );
  }
}


class C extends StatefulWidget {
  const C({ super.key });
  State createState() => BState();
}
class CState extends State {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("C"),
        ),
        body:
        ListView(children: [
          GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
                  return A();
                }));
              },
              child:Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                height: 100, width: 100, child: Center(child:Text("A")),)),
        ],)
    );
  }
}


I was expecting to see route C but only B is pushed then it seems to be broken

In your C state class you are using BState i think that might be the issue so its try to change it to C

Thanks wow just an oversight sorry, glad I made the test case because I am still having navigator issues in my actual project related to calling pushNamedAndRemoveUntil and then any push after that not working (async or otherwise) after a long function call. I added some logging to the navigator and got the result below. If I'm allowed to change the subject anyone have an idea why 9 predicates get formed from looping A-B-C-A  multiple times "[NavigatorState _getRouteBefore] called w index predicate ~ 9" then it repeats 8..7.. to zero while looping these screens

I found this breaks so this is probably my issue  ```          Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, "/B", (route) => route== "/home");
// await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:1)); // breaks
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
return C();
}));

In the C class, you're using BState instead of CState
Change
class C extends StatefulWidget {
  const C({ super.key });
  State createState() => BState();
} 

To
class C extends StatefulWidget {
  const C({ super.key });
  @override
  State createState() => CState(); // UPDATED
}

